# Xbox one controller detect wireless signal

Tags: bluetooth, wireless, xbox-one

Is there any way I could connect my PC and Xbox one controller wirelessly without any additional adapters or hardware?

Why is there no wireless PC emulator for xbox controller? PS has got one. Xbox's suppose to be easier to make because of the SDKs that microsoft provides.

Comment: Just to note, the Xbox One controller model 1708 has Bluetooth. See [Which Xbox One controller is Bluetooth?](https://bigtechquestion.com/2020/04/24/gaming/consoles/which-xbox-one-controller-is-bluetooth/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xbox 360 and Xbox One controllers use a propriety wireless standard. This allows Microsoft to control and license who makes wireless peripherals for Xbox.

It also means these peripherals can only connect via wireless to an Xbox. Anything else requires [an adapter](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/accessories/xbox-wireless-adapter-for-windows-setup) to authenticate it's a valid and translate the data to and from that peripheral.

On the other hand, PlayStation controllers use Bluetooth, which should work with a PC, laptop, tablet, etc without additional hardware.